# Autolayout doesn't work with Nested View

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm new to iOS and autolayout. I'd like to implement a simple UI like iMessage. The structure is simple like,

```
---------------
TableView (for history content)
---------------
charBarView ( contains inputTextView | sendButton )
---------------
```

The constraints for inputTextView is TopSpace/BottomSpace/Leading with charBarView, and Trailing with sendButton. Also I set its height equals 45, while charBarView height unset.

The problem is, when I try to handle user input more than one line, to implement the delegate textViewDidChange. The code :

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView != inputTextView{
        return
    }


    var textViewFrame = inputTextView.frame
    let sizeDiff = inputTextView.contentSize.height - textViewFrame.height

    var chatBarViewFrame = chatBarView.frame
    chatBarViewFrame.origin.y -= sizeDiff
    //chatBarViewFrame.size.height += sizeDiff
    chatBarView.frame = chatBarViewFrame

    inputTextViewFrame.size = inputTextView.contentSize
    inputTextView.frame = inputTextViewFrame

    var tableViewFrame = tableView.frame
    tableViewFrame.size.height -= sizeDiff
    tableView.frame = tableViewFrame
}
```

When I comment the code

> //chatBarViewFrame.size.height += sizeDiff

it looks work fine, but the height of chatBarView is unchanged, so the button is moved up when charBarView changed(I want to keep it at bottom always).

When I put the code

> chatBarViewFrame.size.height += sizeDiff

back, then the charBarView origin and height is changed, but the height of inputTextView will never change.

I use xcode 7 with iOS 8/9.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: fyi: this is the exact opposite of autolayout

Comment: in that case, how should I get the effect I want?